# Why is there no binary created when running `go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc`?

Tags: go

`godoc` and `gotour` can be built and run from their respecitve source directory with `go build`. What is the reason a `gotour` binary created when one `go get` it and that is not the case for `godoc`.

## Command Line Output:

```
[ user@pc:~/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.5.1/global ]
>> ls

[ user@pc:~/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.5.1/global ]
>> go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/user/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.5.1/global"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/home/user/.gvm/gos/go1.5.1"
GOTOOLDIR="/home/user/.gvm/gos/go1.5.1/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=""
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"

[ user@pc:~/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.5.1/global ]
>> go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc

[ user@pc:~/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.5.1/global ]
>> ls
pkg  src

[ user@pc:~/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.5.1/global ]
>> go get golang.org/x/tour/gotour

[ user@pc:~/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.5.1/global ]
>> ls 
bin  pkg  src

[ user@pc:~/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.5.1/global ]
>> ls bin/
gotour

[ user@pc:~/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.5.1/global ]
>> cd src/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc/

[ user@pc:~/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.5.1/global/src/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc ]
>> go build

[ user@pc:~/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.5.1/global/src/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc ]
>> ./godoc 
usage: godoc package [name ...]
    godoc -http=:6060
  -analysis string
        comma-separated list of analyses to perform (supported: type, pointer). See http://golang.org/lib/godoc/analysis/help.html
  -ex
        show examples in command line mode
  -goroot string
        Go root directory (default "/home/user/.gvm/gos/go1.5.1")
  -html
        print HTML in command-line mode
  -http string
        HTTP service address (e.g., ':6060')
  -httptest.serve string
        if non-empty, httptest.NewServer serves on this address and blocks
  -index
....
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Godoc is special as it is an official tool being part of the Go distribution.

So if you `go get` godoc, the result binary will not be placed under `$GOPATH/bin` where all other executables go, but under `$GOROOT/bin`.

Gotour is not special in this way, so it gets installed into your `$GOPATH/bin`.

Comment: It would be nice to know where the special case is handled in go source tree - or official documentation for the behavior. Couldn't find either, but I assume the functionality resides with `build` subcommand.

Answer (score 5):

And for those just *want to* install `godoc` under `$GOPATH` can do so:

---

1. *Download, don't install:*

```
$ go get -u -d golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc
```

2. *Build binary to specific path:*

```
$ go build -o $GOPATH/bin/godoc golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc
```

Comment: Windows:
go build -o %GOPATH%/bin/godoc.exe golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc